# MVVM Unit Testing

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm

I have developed an application in WPF using MVVM because of the added benefits of seperation and test ability. However I am trying to write some unit tests as part of this but am confused about what to test. I know how to write the unit tests, hovever am unsure of what should I be testing in the view model, which is made up of my properties for data bindings and methods for some logic.

Furthermore most of my view model methods are private because they only need to be accessed from inside of the view model so they cannot be simply tested via unit tests like a public method would be. This results in being able to test very little of the view model which opposes the supposed value of MVVM in concerns to testing and from a quality POV is disadvantageous as I have to rely on manual tests to prove the functionality of my code.

I might be wrong and am new to using MVVM but any help would be appreciated on how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

When I write WPF applications I focus my testing on the models.

I test view-models by calling commands and setting properties like the user would do by using the user interface. For trivial view models that just wrap a model one-to-one or call a service with 4 lines of code I don't write any initial tests.

As soon as I find something that doesn't work as expected when running the application I go back and write a test for that particular use case. That initial "bug" usually shows what was tricky to implement in that particular view model and is a good starting point to write more tests and continue development in a more test driven fashion.

Answer (score -1):

You can test the same things that the user can do on your UI.

By definition those things will be public, since the view will binding to them.

eg. Say you have a Widgets collection, and an AddWidgetCommand. You can test that executing the command will add a widget to the collection.